# Type 2 servo velocity tracking

Tags: servo

As I understand from theory that two integrators are required to provide zero velocity lag in a type 2 servo system.  My question is how does 2 integerators help to nullify velocity errors. Less of maths with intuitive  explanation will be useful

Answer (score 1):

Integrators is just a fancy way of saying you want to check your results. A type 0 system simply does not check the result at all. A type 1 system is reading the position directly from the shaft for example. So if there would be any unknown load etc in the system then you could compensate for this position error.

Whatabout a type 2 system? Well since you can measure the position you can deduce what the position should be If you were moving at speed x. This system is supprise supprise an integrator, integrating velocity gives position. So a type 2 system just calculates where the position ought to be if velocity is what you think it should be versus where it is. It can then compensate for this error.

Comment: Not very clear. Velocity to the first integrator gives out position. Now the position is again integrated. How can the 2nd integrator give velocity output

Comment: No velocity lag results in zero output from error detector. There are two integrators in the system. The first integrator must generate constant dc output (for a zero error) followed by the second integrator, which will convert it to a ramp to match the input velocity. But how does it all work? How can an Integrator generate a DC output for a zero error?

Comment: @Vishnu it doesent not in any real system, it provides a reference so that i can adjust the system so it has no error. most likely any real system does not work on analog voltage.

Comment: In addition there is several ways it can work. You would integrate the ramp then you have a position or type 1 problem

Comment: My question is purely theoretical. A ramp integrated twice results in an output which has power of 3, not a ramp

Comment: @Vishnu stop thinking this is math, velocity input is anything, you dont know, it can be a ramp or a sine wave. You do not integrate this function 2 times you integrate it once. The motor does the other integration (since motor position is sum of all input energy), you read the position at the shaft. Now since your direct signal drives position your input signal which is in velocity (any function you dont care, most likely you can not express it as mathematical function anyway), you integrate it once. Now the position and the input are comparable you can now subtract them from each other.

Comment: Its called type 2 servo since there are 2 integrators, the other is in your motor. You could make also both 2 integrators, in similar system and drive the motor from back emf but this is just a bit uncertain.  Now you need to implement integration 2 times yourself. But that is prone to more error than measuring the output directly, and you dont need to implement the other integrator as the motor is a perfect integrator (for your application). Another way to look at it is that you can not measure velocity directly (but that too is possible) very well so you end up integrating the control.